# How to replace part of a Function result in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to replace my `Function` result with a different formatting. Currently my Sub displays the output integer as "**0009594**". I would like my function result to be displayed without the leading 3 zeros, "**9594**".

My function result varies based off UserID from `UserForm1.TextBox1`

**Code**

```
Public Sub employeeldap_office()
Dim struser As String
Dim struserdn As Integer

struser = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
struserdn = Get_LDAP_User_Properties("user", "samAccountName", struser, "department")

If Len(struserdn) <> 0 Then

    MsgBox struserdn
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Msgbox Int(struserdn)?

Comment: `MsgBox Mid(struserdn, 4)` will give you the string after the leading 3 characters

Comment: @ShaiRado how about using that same format to paste the value to a cell, say `$A$1`

Comment: Range("A1").Value2 = Mid(struserdn, 4)

Comment: @ShaiRado when running `Range("A1").Value2 = Mid(struserdn, 4)` it makes cell `A1` = 4

Comment: @ShaiRado declaring struserdn as `String` solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working version:

**Displaying Function result in MsgBox without leading Zeros**

```
Public Sub employeeldap_office()
Dim struser As String
Dim struserdn As Integer

struser = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
struserdn = Get_LDAP_User_Properties("user", "samAccountName", struser, "department")

If Len(struserdn) <> 0 Then

  MsgBox Mid(struserdn, 4)
Else

End If
End Sub
```

**Displaying Function result in cell range without leading Zeros**

```
Public Sub employeeldap_office()
Dim struser As String
Dim struserdn As String

struser = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
struserdn = Get_LDAP_User_Properties("user", "samAccountName", struser, "department")

If Len(struserdn) <> 0 Then
    Sheet2.Range("AB13").Value2 = Mid(struserdn, 4)
Else

End If
End Sub
```